# Circle exercise Java?

Tags: java

This is not a homework,this is an exercise in a Java book I am learning by myself.
Build a class with the name circle which represents a circle in the coordinate plane.The fields of the class should be radius length,dy coordinates of the center.The methods of the class should be :

`getArea()` : Finds the area of the circle

`getPerimeter()` : Finds the perimeter of the circle

`moveCircle()` : Changes the coordinates of the center of the circle

`modifyRadius()` : Modifies the radius of the circle

```
private int x, y;

public Circle() {
   x = 0;
   y = 0;
   radius = 1;
}

public Circle(int x, int y, double radius) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.radius = radius;
}

public double getArea() {
   return radius * radius * Math.PI;
}

public double getPerimeter() {
   return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
}
```

Now how do I continue this? for moveCircle and ModifyRadius?

Comment: just add setters for x, y and radius

Comment: Post the signature of `moveCircle`  and `ModifyRadius` also.

Comment: I think there is an error in your code. Variabile radius should be declared with the other at the beginning of your class. Something like that: private int x, y, radius;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a variable called `radius` in your class.

```
private int radius;
```

to move circle, you should pass your new location of the center to the object. Then it will set the new position.

```
public void moveCircle(int newX, int newY) {
  this.x = newX;
  this.y = newY;
}
```

To modify the radius you also can use the same method.

```
public void ModifyRadius (double newRadius) {
  this.radius = newRadius;
}
```

---

Another way is to create setters for the variables.

```
public void setX (int x) {
  this.x = x;
}

public void setY (int y) {
  this.y = y;
}

public void moveCircle (int x, int y) {
  setX(x);
  setY(y);
}

public void setRadius (double radius) {
  this.radius = radius;
}
```